# Cloudflare Worker Headers breaking Add to Cart Button

Tags: javascript, php, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

After a few hours of digging, I have narrowed down why the "Add to Cart" button for Woocommerce is no longer working; my cloudflare worker! The complete code is below, however the issue is in regards to the header information responsible by:

```
const response = await fetch(request)

 return new Response(html, {
        headers: response.headers
```

I have tried to modify the headers instead, but then the international styling does not work at all. Experimentation is here: https://ellasbubbles.com/product/ella-shower-column-kit-for-walk-in-tub-deck-mount-faucets/. If you are inside of U.S/CA you will not see this issue because of the IF statement.

Is there something wrong with the headers? Should I modify them in a different way? Should I insert my css in a different way?

Cloudflare Worker:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.passThroughOnException()
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Fetch and log a given request object
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
    const country = request.cf.country
    if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') {
    const response = await fetch(request)
    var html = await response.text()
    
    // Inject scripts
    const customScripts = '<style type="text/css">custom css here</style></body>'
    html = html.replace( /<\/body>/ , customScripts)

    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, {
        headers: response.headers
    }) 
}
}
```

I have tried running the code like this, and after clicking "Add to Cart" - the entire page goes blank, because there is nothing inside of the  after the "add to cart" button is clicked

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.passThroughOnException()
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Fetch and log a given request object
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
    const country = request.cf.country
    if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') {
    const response = await fetch(request)
    var html = await response.text()
    
    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, {
        headers: response.headers
    }) 
}
}
```

**UPDATED (Solution)**:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.passThroughOnException()
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
    const country = request.cf.country
    if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') {
    const response = await fetch(request)
    const type = response.headers.get("Content-Type") || "";
    if (!type.startsWith("text/html")) {
     return response;
   }

    var html = await response.text()
    
    // Inject scripts
    const customScripts = 'Styling Here'
    html = html.replace( /<\/body>/ , customScripts)

    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, {
        headers: response.headers
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here.

```js
if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') {
```

It looks like the whole handler function doesn't run if the country is US or CA, which means no response will be sent.

```js
    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, {
        headers: response.headers
    })
```

Here, you're copying the headers from the original response, but you are not copying other properties, such as the status code. Try this instead:

```js
    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, response)
```

Here, all the properties of `response` will be copied over, except for the body which comes from `html`.

Another problem is that you are modifying *all* responses, even if they are not HTML. E.g. you might be accidentally modifying JSON API responses. Worse, if you process a binary file, like an image, then this code will almost certainly corrupt it, because it converts the binary into text. To avoid that, you might want to check the `Content-Type` header before modifying, like:

```js
    const response = await fetch(request)
    const type = response.headers.get("Content-Type") || "";
    if (!type.startsWith("text/html")) {
      // Not HTML, don't modify.
      return response;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will reply to each remark in a new comment.

Comment: The country IF statement placement does not seem to have any negative effect when visiting from inside or outside U.S/CA. I believe because the headers cannot be shifted as the const is not defined nor is the response hit. Would it be best to wrap the entire function?

Comment: return new Response(html, response) - Resolved the issue... something so simple...

Comment: modifying all responses - thank you for elaborating on this. To confirm however, inside the if statement; wouldn't I use "return new Response(html, response)" instead of  "return response;" ?

Comment: No, you should not `return new Response(html, response)` because this implies you read the text into a string called `html`. Reading the content into a string will corrupt it if it is not text. You need to skip the `response.text()` call entirely if the response is not text. The easiest way to do that is to do `return response` before calling `response.text()`.

Comment: Hm, I have incorporated as so (see update in OP) - but now the styling is not working

Comment: Again, you need to add the new code BEFORE calling `response.text()`. You added the new code at the end, that won't work.

Comment: Just updated the solution in OP, thank you again for your help